# How can I cluster buckets of strings?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, data-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have several buckets. Each bucket contains many tags (strings). How can I cluster buckets together based on similarity or overlap?

E.g.

Bucket A: 'ostrich', 'sparrow', 'hummingbird', 'zebra', 'blue jay'

Bucket B: 'banana', 'watermelon', 'grape', 'carrot'

Bucket C: 'celery', 'lettuce', 'spinach', 'banana', 'carrot'

Bucket D: 'sparrow', 'dog', 'cat', 'lion', 'elephant', 'horse'

In this very, very small example, B+C would make one cluster (because of banana & carrot) while A and D would each be in their own cluster because there isn't quite enough to cluster them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set based distances such as Jaccard with hierarchical clustering.